# CalendarWeeks in WPF Datepicker

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, datepicker

As the title of my question says: Is there a possibility to show the correspodending CalendarWeek in the WPF DatePicker-Control?

With WinForms there was the possibility to show it on the left-hand-side of the calendar. How to achieve this in WPF?

**UPDATE:** Thanks to the good answer of `Mare Infinitus` I were able to find the correct (working for me) solution in the blog of [Charles Petzold](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2009/10/Adapting-the-Calendar-Control-for-Week-Numbers.html).

I just had to change the logic to calculate the weeknumber to pass iso-standards! :)

Comment: @MareInfinitus: You're right, I could have written down that I read the docs and looked in the MSDN. Usually your comment is written by me ;)

Comment: Okay then, you will find the source code needed in my answer. hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: Yes, it is possible:

Here is the sourcecode that you wanted:
[Datepicker final with calender weeks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88757/WPF-Calendar-and-Datepicker-Final)

Please take a look on the WeekColumnVisibility property.

For your interest, here is more information on [Customizing the New WPF Calendar Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882520.aspx)

here is a SO [on determining the week of the year (quite easy in the end)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918593/how-can-i-determine-the-week-number-of-a-certain-date)

Here is some detailed information what to do with such a control.
[Introducing the WPF 4 Calender Control](http://10rem.net/blog/2009/10/26/introducing-the-wpf-4-calendar-control)

and, if you like it, here are some quick and hands on examples on calenders [at WPF Tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/Calendar.html)

Comment: But what is strange is that it really needs to be rewritten?! (It was rather dirty but easy in WinForms --> http://forum.codejock.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=17826&title=how-to-show-week-numbers-in-datetimepicker)

Comment: Not everything can be delivered in the first place. Perhaps future versions will have this feature.