# GetWeekOfYear is not working for today date, its returning 28 instead 27

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting a 28 instead 27 of week number with GetWeekOfYear. Is my computer crazy?

Thanks.

Comment: Check to make sure your computers date is correct

Comment: Coul you try this:
                Dim weekOfyear As New Integer

                Dim cul As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture

                weekOfyear = cul.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(Today, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GetWeekOfYear returns the wrong week number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38258118/getweekofyear-returns-the-wrong-week-number)

Answer (score 0):

Your computer is probably fine. C# getWeekOfYear can sometimes count weeks differently based on how you consider in between weeks. I would check this question out to see if it might shed some light on the situation([Get week number for the given date c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710092/get-week-number-for-the-given-date-c-sharp)).

Comment: Thanks, but I tried every way...
                Dim weekOfyear As New Integer

                Dim cul As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture      weekOfyear = cul.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(HeaderString, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday)