# GetWeekOfYear returns the wrong week number

Tags: .net, vb.net, calendar, week-number

I tried this code on three different machines and I keep getting 28 for today's week number:

```
Dim myCI As New CultureInfo("en-US")

Dim myCal As System.Globalization.Calendar = myCI.Calendar
Dim myCWR As CalendarWeekRule = myCI.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule

Dim myFirstDOW As DayOfWeek = myCI.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek
Dim week As Integer = myCal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, myCWR, myFirstDOW)
```

It should return 27. Why do I get 28?

Comment: I get 28 as well (today - 7 July 2016). Can you explain why you think it should be 27?

Comment: This year starts on **Saturday** and today July 7, 2016 is 28th week. Do you calculate **full** week? Week count is **1** based.

Answer (score 2):

On my machine, I get the following values for the en-US culture:

```
myCWR = FirstDay
myFirstDOW = Sunday
week = 28 (with DateTime.Today = July 7, 2016)
```

**This is correct.** By passing [CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendarweekrule(v=vs.110).aspx) and DayOfWeek.Sunday to [Calendar.GetWeekOfYear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear(v=vs.110).aspx), you're telling the method that you want week 2 to start on the first Sunday after January 1 (which was January 3, 2016). So week 1 only has two days.

If you want week 2 to start on January 8 regardless of the day of the week that it falls on, then you must pass the day of week of January 8 (or equivalently, January 1) to GetWeekOfYear:

```
Dim myFirstDOW As DayOfWeek = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1).DayOfWeek
Dim week As Integer = myCal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, myCWR, myFirstDOW)
```

This sets `week` to 27.